# Calculate percentile of value in column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, quantile

I have a dataframe `df1` that has two columns:

```
val1    val2
Fwd     729
jeoq    28.2
ke      225.24
```

And I another dataframe `df2` that has:

```
val1    val2
jdj     184.8
oem     33
kiwe    99.4
frqp    82
```

I want for each value in `df2`, find where it locates in `df1` (i.e find the quantile of each value from `df2` in `df1`) and adds it into a new column in `df2` (i.e the quantile for each value)

So the expected output (the quantile value just to mimic the idea, because I'm not sure how to compute them):

```
df2

val1    val2   quantile
jdj     184.8  25.3
oem     33      67.2
kiwe    99.4    55.2
frqp    82      51.5
```

Any help with that, please?

Comment: Not sure what you meant by *I want for each value in df2, find where it locates in df1*. Can you add expected output?

Comment: I update the question @Sociopath

Comment: Where does the `25.3` value come from?

Comment: It is just to mimic what I need, it is not right, the values here should be the quantile of 184.8 in df1 @SergeBallesta

Comment: I think I can more or less understand. But without more elements, I cannot say more than: `df2['quantile'] = df2['value'].apply(lambda x: find_quantile(df1, x))`

Comment: What is find_quantile? is there a function to calculated, this is actually my question @SergeBallesta

Comment: Findind quantile in a series with only 3 values is weird. In addition, quantiles are normally monotonic and your sample `quantile` column is not. So I cannot be sure of what your really want. If the real `df1` has much more rows, `searchsorted` on a sorted `Series` should give acceptable results.

Comment: This is only an example, you can imagine it as many as you can, the important here is the way how to do it in an efficient way :) @SergeBallesta

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I will assume that you want to know for each value from `df2['val2']`, what would be the corresponding percentile in the sorted values from `df1['val2']`.

You should first build a sorted Series to be able to later use `searchsorted`:

```
dfs = df1['val2'].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Once this is done, finding the percentile is easy:

```
df2['quantile'] = dfs.searchsorted(df2['val2']) * 100.0 / len(dfs)
```

With your sample data it gives:

```
   val1   val2   quantile
0   jdj  184.8  33.333333
1   oem   33.0  33.333333
2  kiwe   99.4  33.333333
3  frqp   82.0  33.333333
```

because all the values from `df2['val2']` fall between the first and second value (of 3) from `df1['val2']`